# Code asks for multiple user inputs, but need to do different things with each separate input

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm a total beginner with Python, so please bear with me!

I'm trying to create an automation that opens documents relevant to a subject at the time that the user's class for that subject begins. All of it is based on the user's input and runs in the background.

My question is: How can I get the code to open different files for each set of inputs?

So far I've managed to code the opening of the document at a specified time. It was easy when I put the file path and time in the code myself, but now I have problems when trying to use the user input.

This is my code so far:

```
import schedule
import subprocess
import time

# Initial user input

subjects = list(map(str, input("""Which subjects would you like to set up?
                               (Separate with spaces.) """).split()))

for x in subjects:
    timeOfSubject = input("What time is your " + x + """ class? Enter in 24-hr
                          time: """)
    fileName = input("""Which file would you like to choose? Please include
                     entire pathname of file: """)
    greeting = input("Leave yourself a start-up message! Enter: ")
    print("Registered!")

# Setting up Document Opening Function

for x in subjects:
    def openDocument():
        print(greeting)
        subprocess.call(['open', fileName])
    schedule.every().day.at(timeOfSubject).do(openDocument)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(2)
```

My output asks all the questions shown in the code above. E.g. if I answer `Which subjects would you like to set up?` with `English History Geography` it will ask me the series of questions for each of those subjects successfully.

The problem is once I have completed entering my subjects, and expect the code to run, nothing happens except for the last subject I entered.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that it's the same source input in the code. How can I do this so it also accommodates for the fact that the user may wish to register an infinite amount of subjects?

Looking forward to any and all suggestions, thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Note how instead of storing them in a list like you did with `subjects`, you just keep overwriting the same variables (like `greeting`) over and over.

Comment: Well. The reason you're only getting the last subject is because when you split() you didn't tell it to split with ' , ' like so: ```.split(",")```
But your code is super confusing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: After you register, what does it do then?

Comment: @daudnadeem I'm just trying to get the code to read the user input and then open the documents registered, but for each subject. I probably skipped useful steps because I'm not familiar with all the possibilities in Python, which is why I asked here. After it registers, it's just meant to run in the background and open the file at the time registered.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'll try apply that, thanks!

Comment: ```subjects = list(map(str, input("""Which subjects would you like to set up?\nSeparate each subject with spaces. """).split(",")))```

This will fix your issue of each subject, I think the rest looks good and should work. I'll rewrite this code later on and show you how I would do it.

Comment: @daudnadeem Subjects are separated with spaces, not commas. Your change will break their code. If you run their code you'll see what the problem is that they're asking about.

Comment: Then you simply do ```.split(" ")```